# Powershell registry access multiple options

Tags: powershell

To access or make changes to registry in a windows machine by powershell, I see two ways

1. `cd HKLM:\` (or set-location -path
   HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion)

   `Get-childitem`

   or

   `Get-Item -path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run`
2. `Get-ItemProperty , New-ItemProperty , Set-ItemProperty`

When to use one over the other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are both necessary, because the property values aren't accessible on the `Item` objects (and you can't see the nested "child" container items with the `ItemProperty` commands).

My 2c: the registry provider was written by someone as a demo, and then shipped and now they're afraid to change it ... it's the only way to explain the whole "ItemProperty" thing.

Basically, when they mapped the registry to the PowerShell Provider semantics, instead of having "Container" and "Leaf" items, there are only containers, and each container has *properties* (and/or child containers).

So if you do `Get-ChildItem HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft` you get a response back listing the "Name" of each of the child containers (which the Registry Editory (Regedit.exe) would show as folders), and listing the values in them under the heading "Property" -- ***but that listing is purely in the display***, and the `Property` field on the object you got back is actually just a string array listing the names of the properties so you know what you can do next:

- If you want to actually read the values in a way that makes them accessible to your script, you need to use `Get-ItemProperty`
- If you want to change the value, you need to use `Set-ItemProperty`
- To create new ones, you need to use `New-ItemProperty`

In your example, for instance, you might see SecurityHealth:

[image: The Run key has a SecurityHealth property pointing at SecurityHealthSystray.exe]

But it's like the screenshot above, as a human, you can see the value, but your script can't read the value...

You have to use `Get-ItemProperty -Path HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run` to get an object back that actually has the `SecurityHealth` property with the `C:\WINDOWS\System32\SecurityHealthSystray.exe` value...